# Change View Controllers After Facebook Login

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uiviewcontroller

[image]
I have my view controller listed below that handles the Facebook Login. As it is now, the app runs and loads a view that has the Facebook login button. Once logged in, the button changes the text to "Log out". What I would like to happen is once a user is logged in, it then goes to another view controller.

I have added a new view controller in storyboard and did a "segue" between the two, but I feel like I am missing something. The new view controller I made is named "homeViewController" if that helps. Thanks

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    NSLog(@"%@", user.name);
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
    NSLog(@"You are logged in! :) ");
}

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
    NSLog(@"You are logged out! :( ");
}

- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *alertMessage, *alertTitle;

    if ([FBErrorUtility shouldNotifyUserForError:error])
    {
        alertTitle = @"Facebook error";
        alertMessage = [FBErrorUtility userMessageForError:error];

    }
    else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryAuthenticationReopenSession)
    {
        alertTitle = @"Session Error";
        alertMessage = @"Your current session is no longer valid. Please log in again.";

    }
    else if ([FBErrorUtility errorCategoryForError:error] == FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"user cancelled login");

    }
    else
    {
        alertTitle  = @"Something went wrong";
        alertMessage = @"Please try again later.";
        NSLog(@"Unexpected error:%@", error);
    }

    if (alertMessage)
    {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                    message:alertMessage
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The segue should be all you need as long as it is attached to the Facebook login button.

If you want you could call

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender {
    if(currentUser ) { //this checks that the user logged in before moving to the next view
     return YES;
    }
    else return NO;
}
```

To check that the user successfully logged in before moving to the homeViewController. 
you would do something like the code above

Comment: So, the facebook login button is highlighted within storyboard, but I am unable to drag it to my new viewcontroller, even while all the way zoomed in. If I only select the view controller that the facebook login button is on, I can then drag and connect via segue, if that makes sense

Comment: @user3079072 So if you can drag the fb button to the homeViewContoller with a segue do it and see if it works. If not make sure the on the right side bar, the third icon from the left of the bar, under class is the correct class.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I added an image in my post to show that the facebook button is invisible per say but is working. To the right is my new homeViewController and the class for that is "uiviewcontroller"

Comment: Well your Facebook button isn't a UIButton, its a UIView, which might be your problem?

Comment: Thats what I am thinking... SO is there not a way to connect the UIView to another view once logged in?

Comment: No. You need to use a button to change to another view controller.

Comment: @user3079072 is that answer correct? is that what you were wondering?

Comment: Well, I see this being done in other apps where people are using the facebook SDK and the documentation states to do it in the way that I set it up. I have no clue on how to move on once the user is logged in. Any suggestions on that note?

Comment: @user3079072 not sure what you mean. Once there logged in more on with what your app is going to do

Comment: Ok so on the main view we are presented with a login with facebook button. Once you press that it asks you for your username and password. Once you do that, the button then changes to "log out of facebook". What I want is once the user clicks "log in with facebook" and the auth happens, when the app returns I want it to go to an entirely new view controller.

Comment: well your going to want a new button on the new page, because you won't be able to see the Facebook button on the login page anymore. And just have a push or modal segue from the Facebook button to the new page. That make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Check this initially

```
FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                      if (status == FBSessionStateOpen || status == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended)
                                      {
                                          //Call your view controller after login
                                          NSLog(@"Logged in!");
                                      }


                                  }];
```

If not logged in, after putting credentials of FB. Under this delegate call your VC to display after logged in

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    //Call your view controller after login
    NSLog(@"%@", user.name);
}
```

Another way is check

```
if (![FBSession.activeSession isOpen])
    {
        // presentLoginViewController
        return;
    }


    else
    {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 //self.label.text = user.name;
                 //self.userProfileImage.profileID = [user objectForKey:@"id"];

                 NSLog(@"FB id : %@",appContext.userName);


                 //Present your view controller after logged in


             }
         }];


    }
```